# Creating a DSpace collection via Java

Tags: dspace

I want to write Java code to create a new *collection* in *DSpace 5.4*.

There exists a static method `org.dspace.content.Collection.create(Context)`, but it is *package-private*, meaning this method can only be accessed by classes in the same package `org.dspace.content`.

Comment: Looks like the docs indicate you are to use `org.dspace.content.service.CollectionService#create(Context, Community)` or `org.dspace.content.service.CollectionService#create(Context, Community, String)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CollinD's comment is correct for the methods to use in the current master branch, what will be DSpace 6 eventually. In DSpace 5.4, the method to use is `org.dspace.content.Community#createCollection()` ([5.x code here](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5_x/dspace-api/src/main/java/org/dspace/content/Community.java#L915)) or the other version of this method that takes a handle string as an argument.

The reason is that a collection cannot exist on its own in DSpace. It must always be within a community, so all public API methods for creating a collection must ensure the community is specified.

To use the method I mention above, you will first need to look up the parent community object for your new collection, for example (if you know its handle) via `org.dspace.handle.HandleManager#resolveToObject(String)` ([5.x code here](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5_x/dspace-api/src/main/java/org/dspace/handle/HandleManager.java#L319)).

There may be other things you need to do to get proper behaviour (eg metadata such as the title); I would look at what happens in one of the UI options when a collection is created there. See XMLUI here: `org.dspace.app.xmlui.aspect.administrative.FlowContainerUtils#createCollection` ([5.x code here](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5_x/dspace-xmlui/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/xmlui/aspect/administrative/FlowContainerUtils.java#L740)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reasoning you provide also fits well with [DSpace's data model](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Functional+Overview#FunctionalOverview-DataModel).